# Why does AVCaptureSession give audio at 44100 but the newer iPhones capture at 48k?

Tags: ios, audio, avcapturesession, microphone, sample-rate

AVCapture session always gives audio block buffers in 44100, but all newer iPhones (since 6 series) capture at 48000.

And you can't specify to the Capture Session a sample rate either!

Does anyone know why this is? I cannot find any info on this. It seems really shortsighted of Apple to do this...

Comment: Is this really any different from your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58895544/avassetwriter-has-an-audio-crackle-only-on-ios-13-devices ?

Comment: No, that's really a solution to an audio crackle, that probably doesn't have an answer other than 'its a bug'. The capture sample rate is most likely unrelated to the crackle issue.

THIS question is specifically, why did Apple do this? No info on this,

At least to my knowledge, of course I could be wrong which is why I'm here.